# How to automatic fill input fields by database values in dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

I have created a php program that dynamically add and remove rows and automatically fills the input field with database value.
The code works perfectly when the first addition of row is done but the code does not show the desired result for when second row is added.
Please suggest a solution as I am new in coding.

```
    <html>
        <head>

             <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

       </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <!-- webslesson_mainblogsec_Blog1_1x1_as -->
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display:block"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4529508631166774"
                     data-ad-host="ca-host-pub-1556223355139109"
                     data-ad-host-channel="L0007"
                     data-ad-slot="6573078845"
                     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                                <tr>

                                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Country Name" /><div id="countryList"></div></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

    $(document).ready(function(){  

      $('#country').keyup(function(){  
           var query = $(this).val();  
           if(query != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"fetch.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{query:query},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          $('#countryList').fadeIn();  
                          $('#countryList').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
           $('#country').val($(this).text());  
           $('#countryList').fadeOut();  
      });  


    });


 });  



    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });



});
</script>
```

Here is my fetch.php code -

```
 <?php  
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing4");  
     if(isset($_POST["query"]))  
     {  
          $output = '';  
          $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_country WHERE country_name LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%'";  
          $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
          $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';  
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
          {  
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
               {  
                    $output .= '<li>'.$row["country_name"].'</li>';  
               }  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               $output .= '<li>Country Not Found</li>';  
          }  
          $output .= '</ul>';  
          echo $output;  
     }  
     ?>
```

Comment: May I ask why you have a document.ready() inside an element click event inside the first document.ready(), document.ready() fires once the document has fully loaded, all your elements have loaded, this happens on refresh or initial navigation to the page.

Comment: Each ID in the DOM should be unique. Your code appears to add the same html string with static IDs on each click of the button - or tries too.

Comment: @RamRaider Sir Thank u. I understand your point but If i dont know how much is to be inserted how can ids be defined.

Comment: @RyanWilson Sir, I am new to coding and I could not get the solution u suggested

Comment: don't use IDs - use parent/child selectors perhaps or set a data-id attribute and find elements that way.